# Reason why unetbootin 494 isn't booting in 13.10

Tags: gnome, 13.10, unetbootin

I need particular unetbootin version to create my ntfs windows pendrive. Anyway, the most recent version installed via application center doesn't support ntfs, and on the internets people are saying that latest working version is 494. So I downloaded it ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/UNetbootin/494/ - 4th file), used chmod +x (it allows to execute binary files in linux, yeah?) and then tried to run it. On doubleclick nothing happens, so I tried running it from console (with sudo) - nothing happens either.

Ubuntu gnome 13.10 x64

If there isn't a solution to this - which other program can I use to write my windows image to ntfs pendrive?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't say why it's not working (failed for me on xubuntu 13.10, too), but an alternate solution would be to try [this method](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/creating-windows-7-bootable-usb-from-linux-762229/#post3946086):

- Format the USB drive as NTFS, and set the bootable flag through gparted.
- Mount the ISO to a folder, and copy the files over to the usb drive.
- Download the latest [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/#Download), extract and compile it. 
  (You don't even have to install it, just navigate to the ms-sys/bin/ subfolder to find the executable after its built)
- Install the Win 7 MBR to the disk with the following command:
   `ms-sys -7 /dev/<device>`  where `<device>` could be `sdb`. 
   this is assuming the iso is Windows 7, check the ms-sys help for more options.
- unmount and enjoy.